# Kubernetes ALL workloads fail when deploying a single update

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

After I update the backend code (pushing update to gcr.io), I delete the pod. Usually a new pod spins up.

But after today the whole cluster just breaks down. I really cannot comprehend what is happening here (I did not touch any of the other items).

I am really looking in the dark here. Where do I start looking?

I see that the logs show:

```
0/2 nodes are available: 2 node(s) had taints that the pod didn't tolerate.
```

when I look this up:

```
kubectl describe node | grep -i taint
Taints:             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoSchedule
Taints:             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoSchedule
```

But I have no clue what this is or how they even get there.

EDIT:

It looks like I need to remove the taints, but I am not able to (taint not found?)

```
kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/unreachable-
taint "node-role.kubernetes.io/unreachable" not found
taint "node-role.kubernetes.io/unreachable" not found
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like there is a problem with the nodes, so they are marked as "NoSchedule", you need to investigate the problem with the nodes.

Comment: Yes, I thought so, but I have not found any issues.

Comment: Can you share with us the GKE version you are using for this cluster and nodepools, and, could you share a complete description of the node avoiding sharing PII?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely problem with the nodes. Debug with some of these (sample):

```sh
$ kubectl get nodes
NAME         STATUS     ROLES    AGE   VERSION
k8s-master   Ready      master    1d    v1.14.2
k8s-node1    NotReady   <none>    1d    v1.14.2
k8s-node2    NotReady   <none>    1d    v1.14.2 <-- Does it say NotReady?
```

```sh
$ kubectl describe node k8s-node1
...
 # Do you see something like this? What's the event message?
 MemoryPressure...
 DiskPressure...
 PIDPressure...
```

Check if the kubelet is running on every node (it might be crashing and restarting)

```sh
ssh k8s-node1
# ps -Af | grep kubelet
# systemctl status kubelet
# journalctl -xeu kubelet
```

Nuclear option:

If you are using a [node pool](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/node-pools), delete your nodes and let the autoscaler restart brand new nodes.

[Related question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56614136/how-to-remove-kube-taints-from-worker-nodes-taints-node-kubernetes-io-unreachab).

✌️

Comment: In fact I think this was probably the case. 
I recreated a node pool and deleted the old one. Suddenly the whole Google Kubernetes interface was a lot faster and everything magically ran again. 

Sigh.

Yes, it did say NotReady.